# Сколько изначально выделяется места программе?

Tags: java, jvm

Как jvm решает сколько нужно выделить места программе?(не используя никакие опции)
Допустим, такой код:

```
public class Solution {
    public void recursion(int n) {
        int m = 2;
        while (m <= n) {
            if (n % m == 0) {
                System.out.print(m + " ");
                if (m == n)
                    return;
                recursion(n / m);
                break;
            }
            m++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Solution().recursion(132);
    }
}
```

Я знаю, что в JVM память делится на два сегмента – Heap и Permanent Generation, heap делится также на два подсегмента (Old Generation и New Generation). В PG хранятся меттаданные об объектах и классы и т.д.. Так вот, в чем собственно вопрос:

- Сколько программа занимает ОЗУ при запуске в итоге? (как jvm решает
  этот вопрос)
- Почему jvm выкидывает OutOfMemoryError, а не выделает доп. память?

Гуглил данные вопросы, написано в основном рядом, но не то... Если есть какие-то ссылки, отвечающие на мой вопрос - скиньте, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Я знаю, что в JVM память делится на два сегмента

Структура памяти виртуальной машины намного сложнее.

> heap делится также на два подсегмента

Это зависит от выбранного сборщика мусора. Поколений может быть больше, а может и вообще не быть.

> Сколько программа занимает ОЗУ при запуске в итоге?

Команда `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version` покажет вам все умолчания для вашей версии виртуальной машины. Ищите параметр `InitialHeapSize` для начального размера кучи и `MaxHeapSize` для максимального.

С размерами *native memory*, которую виртуальная машина использует для своей работы, всё намного сложнее и менее определённо. Почитать об этом подробнее можно [здесь](https://shipilev.net/jvm-anatomy-park/12-native-memory-tracking/).